# Add onClick attribute to WP add_query_arg()

Tags: php, wordpress

I have Google Conversion Tag that needs to add to the WP `add_query_arg()` function.. I tried to Google it but there is no similar info that I am looking.

My concern only is to add another attribute of `onclick="return gtag_report_conversion();"` to the result of this code:

```
$urls = add_query_arg ( 'ver', $value[ 'user_ver' ], get_permalink ( $landing_page ) );
```

Update

We've decide to put the onClick attribute to where the download button is present on an actual interim page, instead of having modifying the `add_query_arg()`.

Comment: That code creates a URL, it doesn't create HTML.

Comment: @miken32 yes i know that. and the code was used in email notification to click the link. I tried to manipulate the code by doing a hard-code of anchor but it was a failure display.

Comment: That won't work. You have to make the changes to the e-mail HTML template instead and, in that case, calling your JS function there will result in a JS error because you won't have access to GA's JS then. You'll need to figure out a different solution.

Comment: Yeah, I admit that. Thanks for the heads-up @cabrerahector